# Struts2 JSON Plugin with Hibernate

Tags: json, hibernate, jquery-plugins, struts2

So I'm trying to create a JSON object from a List of AcaClasses.

Action Class:

```
public class StudentJSONAction extends ActionSupport{

    //Your result List
    private List<AcaClass> gridModel;


    public String getJSON() {
        return execute();
    }

    public String execute() {

        //Get the first student from the Factory and get their AcaClasses
        gridModel = StudentFactory.getAll().get(0).getAcaClasses();

        return SUCCESS;
    }


       //Getters and Setters
```

The StudentFactory is my interface to the hibernate database.

Struts.xml

```
<action name="getJSON" class="StudentJSONAction">
<result type="json">
        <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        <param name="ignoreInterfaces">false</param>
</result>
</action>
```

When I call the getJSON action, all I get is:

```
{"methods":[],"objectName":null,"serviceType":"JSON-RPC","serviceUrl":"\/FlowridersSP\/getJSON","version":".1"}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445956/struts2-json-plugin-not-working-with-lazy-data) problem is very similar to mine but I would like to see if there is a solution using the Struts2 JSON Plugin

Question: Why am I not getting back a list of AcaClasses in JSON form?

My end goal is to plug in this JSON in the JQuery Grid Plugin

Comment: Just to be sure can you add at the end of your execute() method a for each loop to print the contents of gridModel (If you can print it... then it should render as json, if not it isn't a fault of the plugin). Also please show the complete class including getters and setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with JSON plugin, but are you correctly configuring the plugin to serialize the `gridModel`? A quick look at the plugin documentation suggests that you might want to set the `root` parameter also:

```
<action name="getJSON" class="StudentJSONAction">
  <result type="json">
    <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
    <param name="ignoreInterfaces">false</param>
    <param name="root">gridModel</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

Also, try to identify if the problem is with `StudentFactory` or with the JSON serialization. You can set up `gridModel` with a list of dummy `AcaClass` objects and see if the serialization works correctly. Also, as suggested by @Quaternion, you can log the list of `AcaClass` objects loaded by `StudentFactory` and verify that it is loading the expected instances.